Marketing Cloud - SQL Query to Return all Subscribers Who've been sent an email
I want to find out how many of my subscribers (who've been sent an email) have opened an email within the last 5 years. I want to include subscribers who've been sent an email and haven't opened an email within the last 5 years.
The following query returns the error:
SELECT 
    s.[18charcontactid],
    s.[email],
    COUNT(o.EventDate) AS NumEmailsOpened
FROM 
    [Ecomms Full Subscriber List] s
LEFT JOIN 
    _Open o ON s.[18charcontactid] = o.SubscriberKey
WHERE 
    o.EventDate >= DATEADD(year, -5, GETDATE())
    AND o.IsUnique = 1
GROUP BY 
    s.[18charcontactid],
    s.[email]

The following query only returns the accounts that have opened an email, not the accounts that were sent an email and didnt open.
How can i edit this query to show all accounts who've been sent an email in the last 5 years?

Data views store only last 6 months of data. Hence, you won't be able to retrieve data for last 5 years using data views. See here
You have to start archiving your engagement data into a third party analytical data and use that for such use cases
